# Adsense ads displaying full size on mobile

Tags: wordpress, ads, adsense, shortcode

So I have this code set up in my functions.php file on wordpress:

```
add_shortcode( 'testingad', function() {
if( aicp_can_see_ads() ) { 
    return '<div class="aicp">
    <center><script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- AdSense Responsive Ad Code -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-1111111111111111"
         data-ad-slot="1111111111"</ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script></center>
    </div>';

}
```

Then I pull in the shortcode on the page I want the leaderboard ad to appear, like this:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[testingad]'); ?>
```

The leaderboard ad looks great on desktop, but on mobile it's still showing as full size, rather than cropping to a mobile screen size.

I've tried following Google help but it's just not helpful enough for me to understand :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: please share your website link. you can set  mobile screen size ads by using css media query.

Comment: http://photographersbase.com - ad is at the bottom of the page, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify ads by CSS !!!! Google can ban Your account for doing that. If You want mobiles ads, You must choose in adsens flexible ads type when You creating Ad. Ads will not change when You change windows width ( resize browser ) but after reload page they will.